# Find a regex in /dev/urandom and print it to std out in bash

Tags: regex, bash, stream

How can I print a part of a string that I defined with a regex in bash for an infinite stream like /dev/urandom?

I want to pass /dev/urandom to grep or something else and everytime it finds something like [123]+ print it continuously without new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU grep can do the job, but it will output newlines after each separate match when using the necessary `-o` mode, so we can pair it with `tr` to get rid of the newlines.

```
grep -aoE '[123]+' /dev/urandom | tr -d '\n'
```